# How to integrate OpenId feature in .net

Tags: openid

looking tutorials for integrating OpenId feature in .net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling that this [Google Code Project](http://code.google.com/p/dotnetopenid/) will be a great place to start.  I just started looking at it myself a while back, I haven't had much time to dig in, but it looks promising for those not wanting to spend much time implementing.

Comment: It's quite OK yes, I use it in stacked :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want OpenID functionality in .NET you should check out the open source package [dotnetopenid](http://code.google.com/p/dotnetopenid/).

As for tutorials, there are plenty if you don't mind reading tutorials that targets no specific implementation language.  You should check out the [official OpenID site](http://openid.net) for tutorials, as well as the [Wikipedia article on OpenId](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Just answered this somewhere else:

> Found a couple via Google:  [This
>   one](http://blog.madskristensen.dk/post/OpenID-implementation-in-Csharp-and-ASPNET.aspx) is already mentioned.  There
>   are a few controls out there, too, for
>   example [this](http://blog.nerdbank.net/2007/01/aspnet-drop-in-control-to-enable-openid.html)
>
> You could also look at the new service
>   called [RPX](http://rpxnow.com/) which is OpenId as
>   SaaS.

Answer (score 0):

[This document](http://openid.net/get-an-openid/start-using-your-openid/) explains working of OpenID and shows the whole process with screenshots.

[Document](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html) describes how to implement Google login into your web application
and Third-party web sites and let you aware how OpenID authentication works.

[Here](http://www.fryan0911.com/2010/09/use-google-openid-authentication-in.html) is the step-by-step process to implement OpenID on your ASP.NET application using DotNetOpenOAuth libraray.